# Grouping and Sorting XML results in PHP

Tags: php, xml, sorting

Morning

I'm pulling a StockOnHand enquiry from some software called UNLEASHED.

This is a sample of the XML.

```
<StockOnHand>
  <ProductCode>FL1/35/C</ProductCode>
  <ProductDescription>350ml Flavour 1</ProductDescription>
  <ProductGroupName>Edible</ProductGroupName>
  <AllocatedQty>200.0000</AllocatedQty>
  <AvailableQty>8254.0000</AvailableQty>
  <QtyOnHand>8454.0000</QtyOnHand>
</StockOnHand>


<StockOnHand>
  <ProductCode>FL1/65/C</ProductCode>
  <ProductDescription>650ml Flavour 1</ProductDescription>
  <ProductGroupName>Edible</ProductGroupName>
  <AllocatedQty>2.0000</AllocatedQty>
  <AvailableQty>86.0000</AvailableQty>
  <QtyOnHand>88.0000</QtyOnHand>
</StockOnHand>
```

What I'm *really* struggling with is GROUP by SIZE and SORT by AVAILABLE DESC

**GROUPING**
BY SIZE
See how ProductCode has XXX/YY/X?
YY is one of 4 possible product sizes. I get this with
    $size = substr($product->ProductCode, -4, 2);

**SORTING**
by Available DESC

This is the PHP I have set up so far. This correctly shows all products but not grouped by size (12, 05, 25, 50) or sorted by AvailableQty DESC

```
function atUnit15()
{
    echo "<h2>Qty @ Unit 15</h2>";
    $prodXml = getProducts('warehouseCode=UNIT-15');

    echo "<table border='1'> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Days since last sale</th>
                    <th>OnHand</th>
                    <th>On Orders</th>
                    <th>Available</th> 

                </tr>  
    <tbody>";

    foreach ($prodXml->StockOnHand as $product) {
        switch ($product->ProductGroupName) {
            case 'Ice Cream':
                $size = substr($product->ProductCode, -4, 2);
                $code = $product->ProductCode;
                $desc = $product->ProductDescription;
                $saledays = $product->DaysSinceLastSale;
                $onHand = floor($product->QtyOnHand);
                $allocated = floor($product->AllocatedQty);
                $available = floor($product->AvailableQty);
                echo "<tr>
        <td>$code</td>
        <td> $desc</td>
         <td> $saledays</td>
        <td> $onHand</td>
        <td> $allocated</td>
        <td> $available</td>
        </tr>";
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Hi, as I can see in the last piece of code, you aren't sorting the results.
Firstly you need to sort, group or whatever and then you'll be able to print it.
Since you're printing the result on the same foreach, you're never gonna have the sorted table. Regards! :)

Comment: Hi thanks for looking & replying. Exactly -- every iteration of a group / sort I try really doesn't work. I have tried to tinker with this for about 3 weeks and was hoping that by posting I would get a nudge in the right direction. The closest I got with the _grouping_ was a switch($size), it worked by listing just one size. But once I brought any other case: into the mix it began listing the two sizes mixed together.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood your question.
Actually, what's your problem? Are you trying to sort and then, print the table, or have you troubles just printing AvailableQty and Size fields?

Comment: Exactly as you say, my problem is sucessfully sorting then printing the table. `GROUP by SIZE` then `SORT GROUP by AVAILABLE DESC`

Comment: What do you mean `GROUP`? Multiple tables? This feels like two sorts first by *Size* and then sort by *AvailableQty*.  Please show desired results. There is a solution without looping! Also, there must a root in the XML.

Comment: @parfait Grouped by size (e.g350ml/650ml) then by AvailableQty e.g SIZE GROUP 1: 350ml Flavour 1, Qty 55. 350ml Flavour 2, Qty 40. SIZE GROUP 2: 650ml Flavour 1, Qty 78. 650ml Flavour 2, Qty 55

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is using the custom sort function:

Something like:

```
$stockOnHand = $prodXml->xpath('/root/StockOnHand');
usort($stockOnHand, function ($t1, $t2) {
    return substr($t1->ProductCode, -4, 2) > substr($t2->ProductCode, -4, 2);
});
```

1. Using XPath function to retrieve all the StockOnHand, in my case the `root` node wraps all the `StockOnHand`.
2. Use usort, basically expects two parameters, one is your array and the second one just a function, this function will applies the conditions to sort your array.

Put these piece of code just before the foreach:

[usort documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php)

Nice day!